# What to use for generate JavaScript using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, code-generation

If I were to write, in JavaScript, an app that generates JavaScript code (and even interprets it and runs it) what tools/frameworks/APIis could i use?

Comment: Interprets it and runs it where? On the server? In the browser?

Comment: Let's say server. I want to create a JavaScript app and deploy it on  NodeJs (this would be actually step 2: interpret; I also need to generate it...)

Comment: Code that produces code is the first step towards the robot apocalypse. Be very careful.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol that is my goal...

Comment: @Belun: *Literally* laughed out loud.

Comment: @Joe Simmons: a wild idea actually... to use genetic programming to generate javascript code that passes some tests written in javascript (uncle bob presented the idea, in his latest video episode of clean code, that, if you have the unit tests for your app, you could lose and rewrite the app, perhaps even better; didn't fully buy it, but i like the idea; take this further and follow Bret Victor ideas that we should tell computers what to do, not how)

Answer (score 2):

You can run constructed javascript code using eval():

```
> eval("print('hi')")
hi
```

But you should be very careful about executing code that is constructed from user supplied input, as it has access to the environment where the code is executed, for example:

```
> x=3
3
> eval("print(x)")
3
```

In this case access to the variable x doesn't particularly matter, but you can imagine that if the executed code were constructed from user input it could access sensitive data or wreak havoc with the application.

Comment: So, all i need is the text version of my new js code...

Comment: what if my code is huge? what if i have it many files?